# Question about sovolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega=\{(x, y), 0<|x|<1,0<y<1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Define the function
$$
u(x, y)= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } x>0 \\ 0 & \text { if } x<0\end{cases}
$$
(a) Show that $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega), \forall p \geqslant 1$.

(b) Show that there exists a $\varepsilon>0$, such that there is no function $\phi \in C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$ such that $\|u-\phi \|_{1, p}<\varepsilon$. What interpretation does this result allow?

I was able to do item (a), my question is regarding item (b). Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Um.... what is $W$?

Comment: Let $\Omega$ a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $1\leq p\leq \infty$.  The Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is defined by $W^{1,p}(\Omega):=\{u\in L^{p}: \exists \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}\in L^{p}, \quad \forall i=1,\ldots,n\}$

Comment: Did you paraphrase (a), or does the question really state this? The function $u$ is not weakly differentiable, so it does not lie in any $W^{1,p}$ space (which can be seen as a consequence of (b)).

Comment: @ktoi $\Omega$ is not connected, so that $u$ is weakly differentiable with $\nabla u = 0$.